# Create list containing ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', ....] upto 26 'z'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

Question says to create a list having the elements ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd',... ], the last element should be 26 'z's. I need to do this using the for loop, avoiding functions.

What I've tried is a really crude way, but I want a better solution. I included a space in the beginning to account for the multiplication of string, but it gives an extra 'z'.

```py
list1 = []
str1 = ' abcdefghijkelmnopqrstuvwxyz'
length = len(str1)
for i in range(1,length):
    c = (str1[i])*i
    list1.append(c)
print(list1)
```

The output is 27 'z's.

Comment: On a side note, you could use `string.ascii_lowercase` to get a lowercase alphabet as a string.

Comment: It says str has no attribute of ascii_lowercase ....could you please elaborate?

Comment: You need to import the `string` module, not use `str.ascii_lowercase`

Comment: @Techie5879 `import string; string.ascii_lowercase`, it's `string` not `str`.

Comment: @MrGeek It would be nice to do this without libraries...

Comment: You can use the `chr` function to create a character from an ordinal value calculated from an offset to that of `'a'`: `[chr(ord('a') + i) * (i + 1) for i in range(26)]`

Comment: I have an answer, but the question is closed now

Comment: Try this : [i*e for i,e in enumerate(str1)]

Comment: Code Review SE for code review. Code golf SE for short programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `e` in the middle of your `str1` and also an extra space at start

```
str1 = ' abcdefghijkelmnopqrstuvwxyz'
#       ^<<<<<>>>>>>^<<<<<<<<
```

You can use `string` module to get to alphabets simply:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>>
```

So you can use this as direct input:

```
import string
str1 = string.ascii_lowercase
list1 = []
length = len(str1)
for i in range(0,length):
    c = (str1[i])*(i+1)
    list1.append(c)
print(list1)
```

However, without using loops, you can do this as list comprehension easily:

```
[char*(i+1) for i, char in enumerate(str1)]
```

If you don't want to use libraries:

```
>>> str1 = "".join(chr(65+i) for i in range(0, 26)).lower()
>>> str1
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>>
```

Comment: This is why tests are valuable.

Comment: Ah, that fixes it. But I think this is a really crude method, taking the string as ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'....is there a way to iterate from a to z in a for loop? Because here I had to add an empty space too, otherwise a would get deleted from the output

Comment: @Techie5879 I don't get it. Iterating from a to z?

Comment: @BlackThunder I mean running a loop such that each character takes the value a, b, c, d,....using a loop....without taking the string as I did

Comment: Ohk so I got that, but how do i run the loop? @BlackThunder
EDIT: Check this link: https://trinket.io/python/3f7f2ae876
This deletes the 1st 'a'.

Comment: `enumerate` can take a starting index. So you can do `enumerate(str1,1)` instead of `char*(i+1)` although in this case it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both @BlackThunder, you did have an extra `e`. If you want a simpler version, take a look at this:

```
str1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
print( [ (i + 1) * s for i, s in enumerate(str1) ] )
```

Or just using integers:

```
print( [ (i + 1) * chr(i + 97) for i in range(26) ] )
```

Comment: Is there no way to avoid taking the string? Like can't I iterate from a to z on a loop?

Comment: @Techie5879 If you just want to avoid using the string fully, you can take a look at the second solution

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way I could think of:

```
z = []
x = 1
for i in range (ord('a'),ord('z')+1):
    c =chr(i)
    z.append(c*x)
    x+=1
print(z)
```